# Cannot bind ItemsSource of ListBox to the items property of an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `UserControl` which contains a `ListBox` as its only child. I want to expose the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to the outside so I defined this dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(RadioButtonListBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public IEnumerable ItemsSource {
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

I now want to bind this to my `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=myUserControl}" ... />
```

When I try to do this in the designer, the `OK` button is grayed out and when I check `Custom` and enter the binding that way, I get a dialog saying: `Cannot bind ItemsSource of ListBox to the items property of an ItemsControl`

So how do I achieve this, other from plumbing with lots of code behind?

## The code-behind hack

This is the hack I use currently:

- I gave my `ListBox` the simple name `listBox`
- I am using this bit of code:

  ```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", 
                                  typeof(IEnumerable),
                                  typeof(MyUserControl),
                                  new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) => ((MyUserControl)s).OnItemsSourceChanged(e.NewValue as IEnumerable)));

  private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable newItemsSource) {
      listBox.ItemsSource = newItemsSource;
  }
  ```

While this works, I consider it ugly and want a pure MVVM way.

A side note to the potential downvoters: Feel free to do so if you please, but I'd be happy if you let me know the reason for your decision. Thank you!

Comment: "In the designer"? Does it work at runtime?

Comment: Just tested it: Yes it does. So it seems to be another quirk of the designer...

Comment: The runtime behaviour should be the only one that counts:)

Comment: Guess so... but it's not satisfying though...